# Python + Tweepy, Status is a duplicate

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

Currently my Python + Tweep bot isn't working claiming the status is a duplicate. The exact error is

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "helloworld.py", line 22, in <module>
    api.update_status(line)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 230, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy/binder.py", line 203, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: [{u'message': u'Status is a duplicate.', u'code': 187}]
```

The bot source is here: https://ghostbin.com/paste/vbdn4 .
What can I add to work around this error?
Note that the first time running this there were no errors yet after stopping it and then going to run it again, I got this error.

Comment: Debug it a bit: print out the value of `line` variable in the loop body. See on which `line` it fails.

Comment: You must have duplicate  content in your file so when you send it the second   time you are getting the error

Answer (score -1):

you forget to step to the next line of the .txt file you're feeding in the for-loop (it does have multiple lines, doesn't it?), I guess....

I've got the same problem ;-) Tried to solve it with 3 different .txt files and give 3 args in a whlie loop, but this doesn't fly either.

We'll get there....